# Define class name in AOP Logger

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j, aop, spring-aop

Can you tell me if it possible over Spring Boot AOP Logger define in console package and class name which is actual proxied?

For better understanding here is screenshot of my console:

[image]

As you can see there is package and class name of my logger, but my goal is have instead `c.s.b.c.MyAspectOrientedLogger` for example this `c.s.b.s.UserService`

And my Logger:

```
@Aspect
@Component
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MyAspectOrientedLogger {

    private Logger lgr = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Around("...")
    public Object logFunctions(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();
        LOGGER.debug("My some logging output ...");
        return proceed;
    }
```

I know that I can use `joinPoint.getTarget().getClass()` and print that name, but I want it instead logger class. Is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The joinPoint argument offers a method called `getSignature`, which again offers the method `getDeclaringType`, which returns the class object of the class of the method, where that aspect was wrapped around.

You can use it like this:

```
    Class type = joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringType();

    Logger lgr = LoggerFactory.getLogger(type);

    Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();
    lgr.error("My some logging output ...");
```

Result of this is however, that you can't get the logger statically, you have to obtain the instance from the factory in the aspect itself. I'm not sure about performance drawbacks in a solution like this, you would have to test it if you write a heavy load application.

Comment: I would try not to rely on the source code, maybe debug info was stripped during compilation. `pjp.getSignature().getDeclaringType()` is also an option.